# Page template without header & footer

Tags: page-template

I have created a page that doesn't use the `header` and `footer`.

I have closed all the tags, but the page is breaking, nothing appears.

My code is like this,

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: [Blank]
/*
global  $post; ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="ie ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="ie"><![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><![endif]-->
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
Hi
<?php // I will have some php code to run here 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am missing here ?

Comment: Could the issue be that you don't end your PHP comment at the top? You have `/* Template Name /*` to close it you need it to look like `/* Template Name */`

Comment: Hi @Howdy_McGee, thanks for that. That was the issue.